# Check if DateTimeOffset is an interval of a timespan

Tags: c#, timespan, datetimeoffset

Hello I've been trying to figure out how to tell if a `DateTimeOffset` is an interval of a timespan.

For example:
if you have a date of something like:
I've found a solution that works sometimes, but throw an errors others.

```
var bigTickTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
Func<DateTime, bool> isBigTick = (time) => time.Minute % bigTickTimeSpan.Minutes == 0;

var notAnInterval = new DateTime(2022,11,18,9,31,0);

var interval = new DateTime(2022,11,18,9,30,0);
Console.WriteLine(isBigTick(notAnInterval));
Console.WriteLine(isBigTick(interval));
```

but the issue is we get a divide by 0 when we have

```
bigTickTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1,0,0);
var thisThrowsError = isBigTick(new DateTime(2022,11,18,9,0,0));
```

How can I check if its an interval of the timespan regardless of which timespan I want to use?

**UPDATE**

What I'm trying to accomplish is if we have a `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)` when a time is passed in `isBigTick` should be true if the minute is 9:00,9:05,9:10 and so on. If we pass in `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)`, `isBigTick` should be true 9:00:00, 9:00:05, 9:00:10,...,9:59:55. any interval of 5 seconds.

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to do. The issue you have is that `new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0).Minutes` gives you `0`, which triggers the divide by zero exception. You can investigate using `bigTickTimeSpan.TotalMinutes`, which would result in a `% 60`. Production code like that should check for zero anyway, in my book, so you should decide what happens when `isBigTick` gets called with `TimeSpan.Zero`. It is more a matter of deciding what should happen than implementing it. Personally, I would write a unit test first, for this kind of code.

Comment: In other words: what _exactly_ ` its an interval of the timespan` means? You could just pass in the number of minutes you want to check.

Comment: Use the `.Ticks`.